# WCF service error when called from jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I get a 500 error when trying to call the following service with the jquery code below, can anyone help please?

result.status = 500
result.statusText = "System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException"

Here is the SVC service:

```
    [WebInvoke( Method = "POST", 
                UriTemplate = "/tools/data/SearchAll")]
    public JsonArray SearchAll(string tool, JsonObject filters)
    {...}
```

Here is the jQuery service call:

```
    //Generic function to call WCF  Service
    function callService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
            url: url, // Location of the service
            data: data, //Data sent to server
            contentType: contentType, // content type sent to server
            dataType: dataType, //Expected data format from server
            processdata: processData, //True or False
            success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                serviceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: serviceFailed// When Service call fails
        });
    }



    function searchAll() {
        var tool = "1";
        var filters = '{{ "col": "thiscol", "val": "thisval" }, { "col": "thiscol2", "val": "thisval2" }, { "col": "thiscol3", "val": "thisval3"}}';
        type = "POST";
        url = "ToolService.svc/tools/data/SearchAll";
        contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        dataType = "json";
        data = '{ "tool": "' + tool + '", "filters" : "' + filters + '" }',
        processData = false;
        method = "SearchAll";
        callService();
    }
```

Comment: 500 is internal server error something is wrong with the server side code place a debug point and step into code

Comment: The error indicates that your service failed to start - check your event viewer or any other logs you may have to see if there's additional info available.

Comment: It works when I take away the parameters, which is strange. Any ideas?

Comment: If it works without parameters, then a good a place to start looking is at the parameters.  Are they correct?  Is the service handling them correctly?  Etc.

Comment: Got it sorted thanks Tim, I think it boiled down to malformed Json that was being passed to the method

Answer (score 1):

I got this sorted, it turned out to be (among other things) mal formed json being passed to the service method, all lookks good now.

Thanks for the help.